# Recognizing Multple Sets of Opening Tag, Body, and Closing Tag in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to develop a function that converts [bold]...[/bold] into <b>...</b> for my forum.  As of right now, this works perfectly when there is only one set of [bold]...[/bold], however, whenever a second one is added, the regex does not recognize the end of the first [bold] until the second.

To illustrate, if I were to put "[bold]Hello[/bold], how are you [bold]today[/bold]?", I should get this:

**Hello**, how are you **today**?

However, what I'm actually getting is this:

**Hello[/bold], how are you [bold]today**?

Below is my current function:

```
function formatBolds(str) {
    output = output.replace(/(\[bold\])(.*)(\[\/bold\])/g, "<b>$2</b>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need it to change the `.*` to non greedy `.*?`

```
function formatBolds(str) {
    output = output.replace(/(\[bold\])(.*?)(\[\/bold\])/g, "<b>$2</b>");
}
```

- The problem with `.*` is that its greedy and tries to match as many as characters as possible, includeing the first `[/bold]` and following `[bold]` until the last `[/bold]`. The `?` makes it non greedy, and halts the matching at the minimum length match

Comment: "Greedy" usually means the regex will try to make the leftmost, longest match it can.

Answer (score 3):

I think that using a non-greedy match should solve your problem:

```
(\[bold\])(.*?)(\[\/bold\])
```